# Confusion with Securestring

Tags: vb.net, securestring

I am hopefully being a bit thick.
I need to write a program that has a machine local admin account username and password hardcoded into it  (so a normal user can call validatecredentials on a principalcontext)

```
Private Function validateAD(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
    Dim valid As Boolean = False
    Using context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Nothing, "administrator", "hardcodedadminpassword")
        valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password)
    End Using
    Return valid
End Function
```

This is obviously a bad idea, so I was looking into securestring.

However to get data into a secure string, don't you need to pass it in as a regular string, (which is immutable, and thus giving you back the initial security risk)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looking at this code.... http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549109/Working-with-SecureString

This shows the password in plaintext. Also, when he clears the strPassword, this leaves the string in memory.  So what is the point of securestring?

Comment: You can hardcode the password into a method getSecureStringPassoword() which is into another dll and obfuscate that dll so that it can only be accessed programatically.

You can also keep your password encrypted or in Base64 encoded, so that the password is not in humar readable formate. But if someone wants to steal your password, he will eventually.

Comment: My approach has been to store the string encrypted with trippledes (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx) and decrypt it when it is needed).  Makes it a bit more secure, but since the encrypted password and the key to decrypt it are in the code it's not impossible.Good enough for my needs. I was curious about the use of securestring.  It doesn't seem to protect against the type of attack it's advertised to. (namely having a human readable string, sure the securestring itself is not human readable, but you need to provide it with a human readable one to start with)

Comment: @AnshumanChatterjee in the case of Base64, eventually means half a second.

Comment: @Crowcoder: there is no sense keeping an encrypted string with its decode key and salt and algo inside the code itself. And if security is needed then half a day us as dangerous as half a second. Atleast base64 doesnt gives a "security appeal"

Comment: @AnshumanChatterjee agree with you about encryption, I said "in the case of Base64", which is not encryption at all. I do not want OP to get the idea that a simple encoding like that is in any way acceptable as encryption.